# Rails 6: Render a partial if only I'm using a method from my controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, render, partial-views, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a Users controller, with `index`, `show`, `edit` and `destroy` methods. In my layouts/ folder, I have a general-purpose user.html.erb layout that renders some partials. These partials are of course producing errors due some of the info isn't available, like `@user.name`, for example. I've tried to render that partial always when I'm in a `def show` state, something like:

```
<% if Users.show %>
<% render "shared/asides/users" %>
<% else %>
Other partials
<% end %>
```

I've tried several ways and I always get errors. I feel totally lost even trying to find out this on the Rails documentation nothing seems to be indicated there too.

Comment: Layout must be a general thing that does not require to check current action. Your layout has, or at least should have a line with `= yield`, and that's the place where the view for current action goes. So if you have `views/users/show.html.erb`, it will be automatically inserted in place of `yield` inside the layout

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, as you say, you're trying to display things associated with a user, like @user.name, but there is no @user.

So why not check for @user before showing the partial? Or if you have a collection of users, I'm guessing @users?

```
<% if @users %>
  <%= render "shared/asides/users" %>
<% else %>
  <%= Do something else %>
<% end %>
```

Of maybe a bit neater:

```
<%= render (@users ? path/to/partial_a.html.erb : path/to/partial_b.html.erb) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a special layout for your action. Then, at the end of action add layout to render.

```
def show
  ...
  render layout: "custom_layout"
end
```